# As I can call a method in the where clause in LINQ 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, methods, .net-3.5

As I can call a method in the where clause in LINQ or how I can add a condition to show only the existing files?

Objective: to show list of documents that exist on the server

Query:

```
var query = from d in dtContext.documents
where FileExists(d.Id, d.Path) == true
select d;
```

Method:

```
Private bool FileExists (int ID, string Path)
{
    if(File. Exists(Server.MapPath(Path))
        return true
    else
    {
        using (Model.DataContext dt = new Model.DataContext())
        {
            var vDoc = dt.Documents.Where(x => x.DocumentId == ID).FirstOrDefault();
                vDoc.Status = false;
                dt.SubmitChanges();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking "How can I add a condition to show only existing files in a where clause?"

Comment: What's not working? Also looking at that else branch in file exits looks like its doing work aside from validating a file `dt.SubmitChanges()`? This might be a problem

Comment: And why are you looking in a database for file existence?

Comment: The problem is that LINQ does not recognize these methods, (the want to translate to SQL) the problem I get is indifferent to the real problem by making the DataBind () to get DataGrid error page (which worked correctly)

Comment: Besides the obvious design flaws in your approach, the query you have in your example looks like it should work like I'd expect it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call a method in a where that cannot be mapped to a provider function (ie can SQL Server execute the function?).

You need to fetch all the documents into memory. If possible, restrict the columns to limit memory usage.

```
// fetch all documents as an enumerable sequence
var documents = dtContext.Documents.AsEnumerable();
return documents.Where(d => FileExists(d.Id, d.Path));
```

Alternatively, if you know the pathes where you files are located, you can scan the file system to get list of all the files that exist and pass that to you query.

```
string[] filePaths = ....
var documents = dtContext.Documents.Where(d => filePaths.Contains(d.Path));
```

Comment: You can just use `AsEnumerable` here, rather than `ToList`.  You need to ensure that the `IEnumerable`, rather than the `IQueryable` overloads are used, but you still don't *need* to eagerly load everything into a list; the data can still be streamed (or the query deferred until later).  Of course, as long as you have enough memory to do this it's not a significant problem.  In my opinion `AsEnumerable` makes the intent clearer as well, but that is of course debatable.

Comment: +1 to the comment from @Servy using `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable()` when you can't state a good reason is premature pessimisation.

Comment: I did what you suggested (Phil), I receive the error "AllowCustomPaging must be true and VirtualItemCount must be set for a DataGrid with ID DataGrid1 when AllowPaging is set to true and the selected datasource does not implement ICollection."

Comment: 1+ for Servy response on AsEnumerable.  If the database has any significant number of records this prevents the memory usage explosion.

Comment: thank you very much for your response, time and experience, apart from sorting out the problem you helped me understand this issue

Comment: ch20: At the end, you can re-convert the sequence from IEnumerable<T> to IQueryable<T> by using AsQueryable();  However, if you component needs a collection that implements ICollection, you need a list or something similar.